# Python & Pandas Error - Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

Following code gives series is ambiguous error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
y = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Selvan\Desktop\loopdata.xlsx')
arr = y.to_numpy()
marr = np.array(arr)
marr = pd.DataFrame(marr)
lenmarr = marr.shape[0]
for X in (range(lenmarr)):
    Z = 1
    T = marr.iloc[X] * 0.5
    C2 = ((marr.iloc[X] - marr.iloc[X + Z]))
    while C2 <= T: 
        Z = Z + 1
        C2 =  ((marr.iloc[X] - marr.iloc[X + Z]))
```

The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/Selvan/untitled29.py', wdir='C:/Users/Selvan')

File "C:\Users\Selvan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Selvan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Selvan/untitled29.py", line 18, in 
while C2 <= T:

File "C:\Users\Selvan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in **nonzero**
.format(self.**class**.**name**))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

[The excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vybc.png)

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question. Also show a sample of the excel file (if possible also as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Michael, Added the traceback. Thank you.

Comment: `iloc` returns the whole row of the dataframe. Narrow it down to a single cell (number) with e.g. `marr.iloc[X][0]` which will use the first (and only) column of the row.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. This works.